# How to test adding friends (User model CREATE Friendship) in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I was watching Railscasts on how to add friends [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?autoplay=true). I built a User and Friendship model. User can add other Friends.

Models:

```
  #user.rb
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships

  #friendship.rb
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
```

DB

```
  #schema
    create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "friend_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
   ...
```

Controller:

```
  #friendships_controller

class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(friend_id: params[:friend_id])
    if @friendship.save
      flash[:notice] = "New friend added!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error adding friend"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

To summarize, User can add other user as friend by creating a new Friendship object. This Friendship object contains user_id (the adder) and friend_id (the added). I am trying to figure out how to test this on RSpec.

I tried (and various combinations)

```
  describe "POST #Create" do
    it "adds new friend" do
      expect {
        post :create
      }.to change(Friendship, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
```

But it didn't work. I am fairly new at RSpec. How can I test User adding other Friend?

Comment: I believe that it didn't work. because save fails. You should pass `friend_id` in params. Did you try checking status, returned by server?

Comment: ah yes, thanks!! I was missing friend_id. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: added extended answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was in missing `friend_id` param.

However, I recommend you to write a bit different specs:

1) First of all, always check what was returned by the server. At least, check status:

```
it { expect(response.status).to eq 200 }
```

2) This test just tells you that friendship created

```
expect {}.to change(Friendship, :count).by(1)
```

But this is not enough! You also want to know, that it was created for your current user and passed friend:

```
expect {}.to change(user.friendships.count).by(1)
context 'looking at created record' do
  before { post :create, params }

  it { expect(user.friendships.last.friend_id).to eq friend_id }
end
```

Or, which will be much better - you can check that users are now friends (if it is possible with your code).

```
before { post :create, params }
it { expect(user.friends).to include(friend) }
```